# I am everywhere!

Tags: riddle

> I look flat, but I am deep,
> Hidden realms I shelter.
> Lives I take, but the food I offer.
> At times I am beautiful.
> I can be calm, angry and turbulent.
> I have no heart but offer pleasure as well as death.
> No man can own me, yet I encompass what all men must-have.

As said on the title, ‘I am every where’ so does anyone know what the answer could be?

Comment: Don't spoiler parts of the riddle that were non-spoilered when it was solved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> You are the ocean.

I look flat, but I am deep, Hidden realms I shelter.

> The ocean looks flat but is deep, it shelters the sea floor from view.

Lives I take, but the food I offer.

> People have drowned in oceans, and it offers fish to eat

At times I am beautiful.

> The ocean can be a beautiful sight.

I can be calm, angry and turbulent.

> The ocean can be calm, angry or turbulent.

I have no heart but offer pleasure as well as death.

> The ocean does not have a heart and it offers a pleasure in sights, in surfing, swimming etc. It offers death when people drown in it.

No man can own me,

> No one owns the ocean and it will be unlikely that anyone will.

yet I encompass what all men must-have.

> It surrounds land which men must need in order to live.

Answer (score 7):

> It is a Tapeworm

I look flat, but I am deep,

> Tapeworm is flat and gets deep into our intestine.

Hidden realms I shelter.

> It takes shelter in our alimentary canal.

Lives I take, but the food I offer.

> Tapeworm can lead to the death of humans which become manure(food) for earth

At times I am beautiful.

> Microscopic photography makes them beautiful.

I can be calm, angry and turbulent.

> Phases of tapeworm in the human body after consuming, they sleep staying calm

I have no heart but offer pleasure as well as death.

> They have no heart but can kill.

No man can own me, yet I encompass what all men must-have.

> We can't own tapeworm, as it is a parasite but all man become parasites for leading their life on earth by depending on others.

Comment: +1!. Loved that Microscopic part! XD

Comment: [Beautiful Tapeworm](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2F09%2F99%2Fc1%2F0999c1ee37d0ca861633d3188fe95e8e.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F478859372869763827%2F&tbnid=gDGoMhLjkg-p7M&vet=12ahUKEwih87Py8MLtAhVOhEsFHZl0DtsQMygFegUIARC7AQ..i&docid=U4XW0q1K4lDLTM&w=1200&h=1200&q=microscopic%20image%20of%20tapeworm&ved=2ahUKEwih87Py8MLtAhVOhEsFHZl0DtsQMygFegUIARC7AQ) Just kidding!

Comment: Hi, this is a funny one! Do you mind changing the statying to staying/

Comment: I don't see how the second to last part satisfies the 'but offer pleasure' part.

Answer (score 5):

You could be

> The sky

I look flat, but I am deep,

> For someone on Earth, it may seem flat, but it has so much depth to it

Hidden realms I shelter.

> Several layers of the atmosphere

Lives I take, but the food I offer.

> Lives can be taken by storms and tornadoes. It also participates in natural seed dispersion and pollination for plants which may serve as food.

At times I am beautiful.

> The clouds in the sky can be a feast for the eyes

I can be calm, angry and turbulent.

> Could refer to the wind

I have no heart but offer pleasure as well as death.

> Has no centre, but can be pleasant and storms could cause death

No man can own me, yet I encompass what all men must-have.

> No one could practically "own" the sky but it covers all of the Earth.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting answers so far, but I think this one makes the most sense to me:

> `The Ground`

I look flat, but I am deep,

> `The ground often looks flat from a mountain, on prairie plains, beach, from the sky, etc.`

Hidden realms I shelter.

> `Animals live underground, caves exist beneath the surface, and human dwellings can extend into the ground as well (basements, tunnels, bunkers).`

Lives I take, but the food I offer.

> `Humans are buried in the ground, but crops also grow from it. Miners are lost to caves, but burrowed animals are also hunted for food.`

At times I am beautiful.

> `Fresh, snow-covered ground is beautiful. So too are grassy plains, and deserts to some. (Many become desktop backgrounds.)`

I can be calm, angry and turbulent.

> `The ground is usually calm, but sometimes earthquakes can occur, which give the feeling of an angry, turbulent personification.`

I have no heart but offer pleasure as well as death.

> `People sometimes sleep or sit on the ground, to rest. They also fall to their deaths sometimes, and die when they hit ground.`

No man can own me, yet I encompass what all men must-have.

> `No one can own the concept of the ground, but humans have fought wars for millennia to claim pieces of it.`